# ConnectedComponents problem of syntactic structure

Tags: graphs-and-networks

In Mathematica 10, ConnectedComponent computes the list of vertices belonging to strongly connected components. In the following simple example with a graph with  no edges, the result is as follows:

```
 In[29]:= ConnectedComponents[Graph[{1, 2}, {}]]

Out[29]= {{1}, {2}}
```

Therefore the list structure of the result is  { {list of vertices} ...}.

**{** {1}, {2} **}**

However, when I use list as vertices, the result is:

```
In[28]:= ConnectedComponents[Graph[{{1}, {2}}, {}]]

Out[28]= {{{{1}}}, {{{2}}}}
```

The syntactic structure is now { {{ list of vertices }} ...}, that is:

**{**{  *mysterious parenthesis*-->{ *Vertices* --> {1}}}, {{{2}}}**}**

Do you have any idea to circumvent this problem ? Thank you

Moreover, the problem diseappears when an edge is added.

```
 In[30]:= ConnectedComponents[Graph[{{1}, {2}}, {{1} -> {2}}]]

Out[30]= {{{2}}, {{1}}}
```